# Check if socket-client is still connected

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking

I want to implement a while-loop that runs as long as a Client is connected at my socket. 
It's gonna be Thread based so i want to make shure that the Thread gets closed once the Client disconnected.

1. question: How do I check if the Client is still connected to my socket?
2. question: Is the Thread already getting closed when connection closes if I startet it like this: Thread.start(socket.accept) do |client| ...

Comment: Is the client sending you data on the socket? If so just call "recv" on the socket. "recv" will return an error if the socket is closed. alternatively another approach is to use "select" or "poll" to check the status of the socket. Please check for the equivalent calls in Ruby.

Comment: unfortunatly at the moment it just "puts" end "gets" does the "recv"-method still work than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience programming ruby. If it was .Net, what you pretend is not possible without some kind of keep-alive protocol. If the server does not get data from client after x seconds it assumes the client disconnected. The client must have a timer to send something to the server when not communicating.

Comment: I've considered doing so too. But it would be nicer if theres a easier way :) Well still i think i'll have to do so if theres no other way.

Comment: What about if timeout is not the way to know if a socket is close or not?

Comment: @Israel I don't know what that means. Why wouldn't a timeout be the way?

Comment: What Israel means is because under normal circumstances, connections are closed gracefully. Or at least semi-gracefully ( FIN / FINACK or RST ) instead of just disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out,

```
require 'socket'                
th=[]
server = TCPServer.open(2000)

loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    client.puts "server started.."

    # Something

    th = Thread.list
    th.each do |t|
      if t.status == "sleep" # checks all client status
        f = t.kill           # kills thread if client is disconnected
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You may kill the thread or you can store the IP addres of clients using that thread in an array and make a compare with that for exact client.(like, t.addr)

Comment: But how do you know whether the client *is* connected? Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
server = TCPServer.open 12345

loop {
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    ...
    puts "client is offline!" if client.closed?
    ...
    client.close
  end
}
```

You may check "closed?" in "client".